# Copy/Paste URI MIME Type is always null

Tags: android, copy, uri, mime-types, paste

I am trying to implement copy/paste functionality in my App. I have been following the [Copy and Paste](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html) section on Android Developer but I guess I did something wrong because it does not work. The problem is that upon pasting, `uriMimeType` is always null and I don't understand how Uri MIME type exactly works. Note that `pasteUri` points to the exact same file as `copyUri`. My code is as follows:

```
private static void copy() {
    ...
    Uri copyUri = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "My URI", copyUri);
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}

private static void paste() {
    ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    if (!(clipBoard.hasPrimaryClip())) return; // The clipboard has no data
    if (!(clipBoard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN))) {
        // The clipboard has data, but it is not plain text. We will now proceed to check if it is an URI.
        ClipData clip = clipBoard.getPrimaryClip();
        if (clip != null) {
            ClipData.Item item = clip.getItemAt(0);
            // Try to get the item's contents as a URI
            Uri pasteUri = item.getUri();
            if (pasteUri != null) {
                // Check if it is a content URI
                String uriMimeType = contentResolver.getType(pasteUri);
                // If the return value is not null, the URI is a content URI
                if (uriMimeType != null) {
                    // uriMimeType is always null!
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // The clipboard has data and it is plain text
        ClipData.Item item = clipBoard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
        String pasteData = (String) item.getText().toString();

        if (pasteData != null) {
            // Do some stuff
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the pasteUri value?